# Show that f is not continuous at a?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $a\in \mathbb R$ and $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be defined by $f(x) = 1$ when $x > a$, and otherwise $f(x)=0$. Show that  $f$ is not continuous at $a$.

This problem is in a section on open balls and neighborhoods. I can show that it's continuous every where other than $a$, but I can't think of a reason it wouldn't be continuous at $a$.

Comment: Draw the graph of $f$.

Comment: Does it exist an open set $S = ]a-h,a+h[$ such that $f(S) \subset ]f(a)-\frac{1}{2}, f(a)+ \frac{1}{2}[$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$. If $f$ would be continuous at $x=a$, then there has to be a ball $B(a,\delta)$ such that $f[B(a, \delta)] \subseteq B(f(a), \epsilon) = (-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$.

This cannot be as $x+\frac{\delta}{2}$ maps to 1 and $a$ maps to 0 under $f$. So the image of the ball cannot be contained in said interval.

Comment: But couldn't I just say ε=2 and then it would work?

Comment: No, because then any $\delta$ *would* work for the above inclusion. Continuity means that for *all* $\epsilon$ we can find such a $\delta$. So find one suitable $\epsilon$ for which no $\delta$ exists and then we have proved non-continuity.

Comment: OH! Okay got it. Thanks.